# Change Action from Edit to View for product in magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, permissions, user-roles, product-review

I have different users with different user roles.

I want to change the Edit option to View only for the users who have not added this product.

***see attach image***

[image]

How can I do that?

Allowing Edit to users who have added the product.

The rest can only view it.